# Gradle and Cordova trouble building

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

Here is the error I got when trying to build my project.

```
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy and 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloCordova'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

cordova requirements is saying that everything is fine :

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-34,android-33
Gradle: installed /home/yuniemos/Téléchargements/gradle-7.6.1/bin/gradle
```

I've tried changing java sdk and gradle version (gradle was originally 8.1.1 and I came back to 7.6.1). I've looking at so much forums and yet I found nothing to help solve my problem. It's been an entire day of looking and I still didn't manage to make it build.

Is there something I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jbr
```

Comment: which version of Java is in the path you mentioned?

Comment: if that's the file under `/platform`, you shouldn't be messing with generated files and this is not a solution